# Why is the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-corank of $\operatorname{Sel}_{p^\infty}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ finite?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm interested on the Mordell-Weil rank of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. I read that the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-corank of the $p^\infty$-Selmer group $\operatorname{Sel}_{p^\infty}(E)\doteq\displaystyle\varinjlim_{e\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Sel}_{p^e}(E)$ is expected to be the Mordell-Weil rank of $E$. But I don't understand much about the structure of this group, other than that the sequence $$0\to E(\mathbb{Q})\otimes(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)\to\operatorname{Sel}_{p^\infty}(E)\to {\large Ш}(E)[p^\infty]\to 0$$splits, let alone about the finiteness of the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-corank. Can someone explain to me or give a reference for why this is true, please? If possible, I would like also some light on the torsion part of $\operatorname{Sel}_{p^\infty}(E)$, so I can understand better its structure as a whole. (I'm sorry if those are trivial questions, perhaps I'm missing something).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $\mathbb{Z}_p$-corank of the $p^\infty$-Selmer is bounded from above by the $\mathbb{F}_p$-dimension of the $p$-Selmer, which is finite by weak Mordell-Weil.

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thank you very much @AlexB. !

Comment: @AlexB. Sorry to return to this question, but I'm a bit unsure if I really understood. Would it be that the Pontryagin dual of $\mathrm{Sel}_{p^\infty}(E)$ is a subgroup of the Pontryagin dual of $\mathrm{Sel}_p(E)\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}\mathbb{Z}_p$ (that should have $\mathbb{Z}_p$-rank $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathrm{Sel}_p(E))$)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what you mean by $\bullet \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}\mathbb{Z}_p$, since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is not an $\mathbb{F}_p$-module in any reasonable way. I will try to write out a proper answer later.

Comment: @AlexB. Oh, indeed... I was trying to find something with $\mathbb{Z}_p$-corank $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathrm{Sel}_p(E))$, but it seems that what I was thinking doesn't make any sense then. Your answer would be a very much appreciated help.